# xgb.DMatrix Error: The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

Tags: r, matrix, xgboost

I am using xgboost in R.

I created the xgb matrix fine using a matrix as input, but when I reduce the number in columns in the matrix data, I receive an error.

This works:

```
> dim(ctt1)

[1] 6401 5901

> xgbmat1 <- xgb.DMatrix(
     Matrix(data.matrix(ctt1)),
     label = as.matrix(as.numeric(data$V2)) - 1
  )
```

This does not:

```
> dim(ctt1[,nr])

[1] 6401 1048

xgbmat1 <- xgb.DMatrix(
    Matrix(data.matrix(ctt1[,nr])),
    label = as.matrix(as.numeric(data$V2)) - 1)
```

> Error in xgb.setinfo(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) : 
>     The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

Comment: Perhaps a problem with missing data?

Comment: thx. I checked, and there is no missing data.

Comment: BTW, nr is the array that choose from ctt1 columns

Comment: dimension of the data

Comment: You posted `dim(ctt1)` value but not what was returned by `dim(data)`.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you report eventual success, but you questions is a mess because it uses both `ctt1` and`data` as object names in the sam expression,  and unlikely to be helpful to people in the future, so I suggest you just delete it.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I fixed this error by changing assign operation:

`labels <- df_train$target_feature`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that by removing some columns, there are some rows with all 0s, and could not contribute to model.

Answer (score 2):

For sparse matrices, xgboost R interface uses the CSC format creation method. The problem currently is that this method automatically determines the number of rows from the existing non-sparse values, and any completely sparse rows at the end are not counted in. A similar loss of completely sparse columns at the end can happen with the CSR sparse format. For more details see [xgboost issue #1223](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1223) and also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) on the sparse matrix formats.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way for creating the DBMatrix Like

```
    xgtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(X_train[,-5]), label = `X_train$item_cnt_month)`
```

drop the label column in data parameter and use same data set for create label column in index five i have item_cnt_month i drop it at run time and use same data set for referring label column

Answer (score 0):

Before splitting your data, you need to turn it into a data frame.
For Exemplo:

data <- read.csv(...)

data = as.data.frame(data)

Now you can set your train data and test data to use in your "sparse.model.matrix" and "xgb.DMatrix".